# Change datatype of list fetched from PostgreSQL from NoneType to int

Tags: python, postgresql, integer, psycopg2

I try to iterate over data I fetched from a database from PostgreSQL. However, my data is a list of tuples containing Nonetype objects, thus I'm not able to compare it with > 4.

```
import psycopg2

# connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='masterarbeit', user='postgres', password='####', port=5432)
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "select min(id), max(id) from bsd_horizonte;"
cur.execute(sql)
gidsextent = cur.fetchall()
minimum = gidsextent[0][0]
maximum = gidsextent[0][1]


for gid in range(minimum,maximum+1):
    weizenausschluss = False
    sql = "select grobbod_k, boart from bsd_horizonte where id = " + str(gid) + ";"
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    if len(data) > 0:
        steine = data[0][0]
        boden = data[0][1]
        if steine > 4:
            weizenausschluss = True
        if boden == "Ss" or boden == "Su" or boden == "Tt":
            weizenausschluss = True
        if weizenausschluss == False:
            sql = "update bsd_horizonte set weizen_ok = True where id = " + str(gid) + ";"
            cur.execute(sql)
            conn.commit()
        else:
            sql = "update bsd_horizonte set weizen_ok = False where id = " + str(gid) + ";"
            cur.execute(sql)
            conn.commit()
    print(gid)
        
# Close communication with the database
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Master Thesis\Python\Code\Code Bitterich\A06 wheat_horizon_ok.py", line 32, in <module>
    if steine > 4:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

How can I change the datatype of steine to int and of boden to string?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `steine/boden` is `None`, you could use a logical `or` to set a 'default' value:

```
>>> data = [[None, None]]
>>> steine = data[0][0] or -1
>>> boden = data[0][1] or ''
>>> steine > 4
False
```

Alternatively, change your `if` condition:

```
>>> data = [[None, None]]
>>> steine = data[0][0]
>>> if steine and steine > 4:
...     weizenausschluss = True
```

Or change your SQL, using `COALESCE`:

```
sql = "select COALESCE(grobbod_k, 0), COALESCE(boart, '') from bsd_horizonte where id = " + str(gid) + ";"
```

So Postgres should use `0` or an `empty string` in case the column values are `null`.